# XSL Skipping Child Element

Tags: xslt

I want to skip the child element from following xml

```
<person id="101">
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <last-name>XXX</last-name>
</person>
<person id="101">
    <name>YYY</name>
    <last-name>BBB</last-name>
</person>
```

Assuming I want to skip last-name and here is my code

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//person [not(last-name)]" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="person">
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

The above code skips the all person element who has last-name element.

Can any any one help me with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper input:

```
<root>
    <person id="101">
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <last-name>XXX</last-name>
    </person>
    <person id="101">
        <name>YYY</name>
        <last-name>BBB</last-name>
    </person>
</root>
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="last-name"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produce what I think is the desired result:

```
<root>
    <person id="101">
        <name>XYZ</name>
    </person>
    <person id="101">
        <name>YYY</name>
    </person>
</root>
```

**Note**: Identity Transform. Empty template to strip nodes.

Comment: @jason4: You are wellcome! Also, in order to help others, please, edit your question and make clear that you want to strip `last-name` element.

Answer (score 1):

By "skip last name" I take it you want your output to look like this:

```
<person id="101">
  <name>XYZ</name>
</person>
<person id="101">
  <name>YYY</name>
</person>
```

In which case your approach will have to include all `person` elements. A standard way of copying everything but a particular element works like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//person"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="last-name">
  <!-- Do nothing, you don't want to copy this. -->
</xsl:template>
```

I think you are misunderstanding how XPath expressions work. Your expression `//person [not(last-name)]` is selecting all `person` elements matching the condition `not(last-name)`, which means it matches any `person` elements which do not have child `last-name` elements. It's behaving exactly as it should.

Comment: Please do not recommend expressions that begin with `//` because they are very inefficient.